No he podido crear un entorno virtual de python con conda
cuando intento crear
conda create -n envexperimental

me responde lo siguiente:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

pero a los segundos muestra esto:
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.
'https//repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'

¿Cómo resolver este problema?, o puedo seguir trabajando así, cuando listo los entornos virtuales no sale el que supuestamente hizo.

El propio mensaje de error sugiere reintentar, ¿lo has hecho?  Si eso no funciona, suena a un problema de conectividad. Has intentado hacer un telnet a repo.anaconda.com en el puerto 443? Logras conectar? el DNS resuelve el dominio?

Intenta copiar los siguientes archivos:

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Desde el folder D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin a D:\Anaconda3\DLLs
Fuente: Issues with installing python libraries on Windows

ya lo hice y nada...gracias
